# Effects of sched_yield() from a thread running with SCHED_RR scheduling policy

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have a process under Linux consisting of two threads, one producer and one consumer. For simplicity, assume this is the only process running in the system on a single-core, single-CPU architecture.

The producer is created first and is manually assigned a `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy with `sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &params)`. After some time, the consuming thread is created too. As it's created after `sched_setscheduler` has been called for the producer, it does not have the same `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy set.

Under this situation, I am trying to understand the effects of `sched_yield()` from the producer (once one element is produced).

There are two possibilities, but I am not sure which one is true:

1. the consumer **may** be scheduled for execution before the producer runs again
2. the consumer **cannot** be scheduled for execution because it is not being run with the `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy **and** the producer did not complete its assigned quantum time or did not `sleep`. In which case `yield()` might  have negative effects, as it's called for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what happens in practice, formally `sched_yield` does not allow a lower-priority thread to run in this case; it's only for yielding to same-priority threads.

You should be using condition variables or some other proper synchronization mechanism to ensure that your consumer gets to run (the producer should `pthread_cond_wait` on the predicate that the queue is above some fullness threshold or similar) rather than trying to do sleep/yield-based scheduling.